# Assembly INT 13h - read disk problem

Tags: assembly, dos, disk

I need to be able to write a program in assembly to read the first sector of a disk (The MBR) and write it to a floppy disk or at least show the data.
I understand that INT 13h and 25h do not work in the windows protected mode and i even tried my code in Dos but the dos system hangs when I run the program. This is the code:

```
  MOV byte ptr es:[bx], offset result
  MOV     AL,1 ;number ofsectors to read
  MOV     Cl,1 
  MOV     ch,0  
  mov     dl,80h  ;the HDD
  mov     dh,1
  mov ah,02h
  INT     13h
```

result is the buffer variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the 'code' feature to markup code for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeb. it finally worked. This is the code (only runs in DOS because the INT 13h can't run in windows OSes.

```
            mov dx,80h
        mov cx,1
        mov bx,ds
        mov es,bx
        mov bx,offset result
        mov ax,0201h
        int 13h
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is wrong

```
MOV byte ptr es:[bx], offset result ' attempts to write memory [bx]
```

It should be

```
MOV es, segment_offset ' probably not needed
MOV bx, buffer_offset
...
```

And maybe you also have to restore the `ES`, example

```
push es
mov  es, ...
...
pop  es
' done
```

Comment: Thanks Nick D
I changed my code to this:

        mov     dx,80h                  ;first physical disk
        mov     cx,1                    ;head 1, sector 0
        mov     bx,ds                   ;
        mov     es,bx                   ;point to boot record buffer
        mov     bx,OFFSET result           ;read into boot record
        mov     ax,0201h                ;read one sector
        int     13h

It seems it works. It gives me a lot of junk when I print it out but how do I make sure it's the real MBR?

Thank you all for your patience in reading my questions.

Comment: @Auxiliary, check out http://mirror.href.com/thestarman/asm/mbr/STDMBR.htm which provides a lot of info about MBR.