# Shared pointer is working without assigning

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Shared pointer is working without assign memory to Win class.

**Code:**

```
class Win
{
public:
    void disp()
    {
        //Do something
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Win> sharedptr;///holds null pointer
    sharedptr->disp();//// why its working
}
```

Why it's calling above function without assign memory to it. Could someone help me out of this?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, everything can happen including the behavior you are observing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can C++ compiler optimize incorrect hierarchical downcast to cause real undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278199/how-can-c-compiler-optimize-incorrect-hierarchical-downcast-to-cause-real-unde)

Comment: why it should not? The function isnt using any member variables.

Comment: See my answer on the other question. Basically, it is still wrong, but happens not to crash because the function doesn't do anything interesting with member data.

Comment: Please see here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
class Win
{
    public:
 void disp(){std::cout << x;}
 int x=5;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Win> sharedptr;///holds null pointer
    sharedptr->disp();//// why its working
}
```

You will not get 5. You may get anything. Like the guys in the comments said, it is undefined behaviour .